# Launch ionic app on ipad in command line without xcode

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, signing

I am developping an application with ionic and I would like to use another IDE (WebStorm) than xcode to edit the code. I would like to run the application on ipad Through Webstorm (either on command line or int the "run" configuration of webstorm).

My build.json

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXXX",
      "provisioningProfile": "blabla",
      "packageType": "development"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to run from command line or in "run", i get this error

```
Code Signing Error: Provisionning profile " iOs Team Provisionning
profile: com.Company" is Xcode managed, but settings require a manually managed profile
```

Xcode generates automatically the provisionning profile, so When i run the app through xcode with automatic signing it works fine, but I would like to use webstorm. Is there a way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach ( Typically what i used to do )

For the First time, .xcodeproj file in platforms/ios/ in Xcode and build once using automatic signing.

From Next time Use this Command in Webstrom Terminal :

```
ionic cordova run ios --device
```

Comment: Thanks ! The application has installed on the ipad and i can launch it, but in the command output i can read "application has not been launch" (error: process launch failed: Security) is it normal ? If I understand correctly, i just can't launch the application from the command line (that wouldn't be so harmful I just want to know if it's normal)

Comment: ( error: process launch failed: Security )  is Quite normal, as Apple wants to Trust the App. 
Just Trust the Developer App once ie. On your iPad

Settings → General → DeviceManagement → DeveloperApp → Trust.

From Next build onwards your App will be launched correctly.